# Creating custom Html helper for datepickerfor(model=>model.date) from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

I am creating custom html helper for my datepicker.
i want to pass inside mode as it is for TextBoxFor(model=>model.name)

so what i need is, but i have no idea how to do that

1. Name of the field
2. Value of the field

I have created

```
public static string DatePickerFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression){

//return object.name
var expressionText = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);


}
```

Comment: @NickLarsen, yes, there is. And there is also [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458151/creating-custom-html-helper-for-datepickerformodel-model-date-from-model/5462079#5462079).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Name of the field

   ```
   string fullHtmlFieldName = htmlHelper
       .ViewContext
       .ViewData
       .TemplateInfo
       .GetFullHtmlFieldName(
           ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)
       );
   ```
2. Value of the field

   ```
   var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(
       expression, htmlHelper.ViewData
   );
   object value = metaData.Model; // will be of type TProperty
   ```

Comment: Thank you,this was exactly what i have been looking for (sorry could not test it earlier.. too much to do) Pav

Comment: i better take ur icq/ twitter / im so i could ask directly :D

Comment: @Pavel, you could always reach me by email.